# vue: design a dynamic "window" component like bootstrap modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a generic HTML Window from Vue application.

### What I want

I click "edit" on item from list, a DHTML popup will be opened with a Vue component inside. I can click Save or close the opened component need to removed from the page and may the caller recive a event/promise with resolve (Save) or reject (Close).

### What I am tried

I was started via DOM:

```
function Win(vueapp,obj) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var Win = JQueryOldFunction()

     //need a way to  resolve when the user hit 'Save' and reject  when closing
     var resolve,reject, promise = new Promise(function(a, b) {
            resolve=a, reject=b;
     });

    new Vue({
        el: div,
        data:  {data:obj} //need a way to pass it to the  component
        render: function (h) {
            return h("m");
        },
        components: {
            'm': httpVueLoader(vueapp+'.vue') // this from https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader
        }
    });

return promise;
}
```

This is working, but I can't use Vue to destroy the window after clicking save, and  can't pass objects inside

so I was tried other option:

```
 <component :is="gui.window" transition="fade" transition-mode="out-in"></component>
Model.gui.window='EditGroup'
```

(took from here: https://coligo.io/dynamic-components-in-vuejs/ )

This is better, it working, does not allowing more than one window, but the internal component can't destroy itself.

Comment: I have tears of nostalgia in my eyes. It's really long time ago since I last seen the DHTML abbreviation...

Comment: PS: Although you can create a new, and then destroy the existing Vue instance on demand, it is a unnecessary complication. Just create one instance and use (show) it as needed and you will spare the time needed to creation and compilation an instance again and again.

Comment: If the window is the same one, you are right. I am using function like this to open a large list of  Vue-Powered  small widnows, so the  component inside can change from time to time.